# Scala inner class typing

Tags: scala, inner-classes

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Deck[+T] {
    class Card(value: T)
    class Pile(val cards: List[Card]) {
        val deck = Deck.this
        def shuffle(shuffler: Shuffler): shuffler.shuffle(this)
    }
}

trait Shuffler {
    def shuffle[T](pile: Deck[T]#Pile): pile.type
}

object Shuffler {
    def randomShuffler(r: Random): Shuffler = new Shuffler {
        override def shuffle[T](pile: Deck[T]#Pile): pile.deck.Pile = {
            new pile.deck.Pile(r.shuffle(pile.cards))
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing without having the `val deck` declaration in `Pile`?  Also, is it possible to do the same thing without the `T` declaration in `shuffle()`?

I had been playing around with things such as `pile: x.Pile forSome {val x: Deck[_]}`, but they don't seem to compile due to typing issues (read: me not fully understanding semantics therein), and I'm trying to avoid rewriting `Shuffler` to, say, work with raw lists instead (how do I express that, anyways?  `List[Deck[T]#Card]` is not quite there, since I want lists of `Card`s from the same `Deck`).

Comment: I probably don't understand what you are going for here, but wouldn't it make sense for the definition of `Card` and `Pile` to exist outside of `Deck`? If they need to use the same type as `Deck` you could always parameterize `Card[T]`

Comment: `class Deck[+T](val cards: Set[Card[T]]); class Card[T](value: T)`

Comment: The reason why `Pile` and `Card` are inner classes of `Deck` is partly to enforce the fact that `Card`s are associated with only a single `Deck` instance. (That is, think of `Deck` as an object encapsulating a universe of `Card`s.)

Comment: For the `List` thing, does `List[deck.Card] forSome { val deck: Deck[_] }` work?. (`forSome` is outside the `List`, so there is only one `Deck` across all elements.)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do the same thing without having the `val deck` declaration in `Pile`?

*Not* if we want to enforce a value dependent type, which you seem to want (e.g. two `Pile[Int]` being only compatible if they refer to the same deck value).

> Also, is it possible to do the same thing without the `T` declaration in `shuffle()`?

You can move type parameters to type members, this can sometimes save you from needing to specify them when they are only internally used.

Here is an idea:

```
object Pile {
  def apply(deck0: Deck): Pile { type D = deck0.type } = new Pile {
    val deck  = deck0
    type D    = deck0.type
    val cards = deck.cards.toList
  }
}
trait Pile { self =>
  type D <: Deck
  type Self = Pile { type D = self.deck.type }

  val deck : D
  def cards: List[deck.Card]

  def shuffle(shuffler: Shuffler): Self = shuffler.shuffle(this)
}

object Deck {
  def apply[A1](values: Set[A1]): Deck { type A = A1 } = new Deck {
    type A = A1
    val cards = values.map(Card(_))
  }
}
trait Deck {
  type A

  case class Card(value: A)

  def cards: Set[Card]
}

trait Shuffler {
  def shuffle(pile: Pile): pile.Self
}
```

```
object Shuffler {
  def randomShuffler(r: util.Random): Shuffler = new Shuffler {
    def shuffle(pile: Pile): pile.Self = new Pile {
      type D    = pile.deck.type
      val deck  = pile.deck
      val cards = r.shuffle(pile.cards)
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
val deck  = Deck(Set(1 to 10: _*))
val pile0 = Pile(deck)
pile0.cards
val sh    = Shuffler.randomShuffler(util.Random)
val pile1 = pile0.shuffle(sh)
pile1.cards
```

As you can see, enforcing value dependent types is not trivial, so the question is if you really need them, or you are ok with a simple type parameter for `A`. For example, the above doesn't prevent you from accidentally putting the same card twice into a pile.